# oauth2login with ressourceServer

Tags: spring, oauth-2.0

i have this configuration for my security chain filter:

```
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        return httpSecurity
                .authorizeHttpRequests(requests-> requests
                        .requestMatchers(requestMatchers).permitAll()
                        .anyRequest().authenticated())
                .sessionManagement(sm->sm.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .headers(hs -> hs.frameOptions(HeadersConfigurer.FrameOptionsConfig::disable))
                .cors(Customizer.withDefaults())
                .csrf(getCsrfConfigurerCustomizer())
                .oauth2ResourceServer(oauth2->oauth2.jwt(Customizer.withDefaults()))
                .build();
    }
```

And i would like to add oauth2Login in order to have the possibility to register a user with google or github authentication.
How can i do ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am beginner to spring security, don't know why you have used the `oauth2ResourceServer()` method but in my knowledge on how to implement oauth2login with google for example you have to chain the `oauth2Login()` on after `authorizeRequests()` for custom login and google login but if don't want custom login, no need to use `http.authorizeRequests()` just use http.oauth2Login and in it override its Lambda to customize the login like success and fail handlers. like below

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class MySecurityConfig  {
    @Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws  Exception{
        http.authorizeRequests(
                (authorizeRequests)->authorizeRequests.anyRequest().authenticated()
        ).oauth2Login(oauth2Customize->oauth2Customize
                .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
                .loginPage("/oauth2/authorization/google")
                .successHandler(new AuthenticationSuccessHandler() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
                        request.authenticate(response);
                    }
                })
        );
        return http.build();
    }
```

in your application.properties file make sure you have added the credentials. By default this is applied when a user visit restricted pages. You can customize according to yours